# How to store pixel data efficiently and pack byte data

Tags: java, image, export, arrays, pixel

I have created a simple class that encodes and array of `bytes` into pixels for a `BufferedImage`. I am using a byte array and packing every 4 `bytes` into an `ARGB` value when writing the image out. I feel that there is an easier way to do this. I there a better way to store pixel data?

The code produces this tiny image, but it can be scaled to export *any* size **→** [image] **←**

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PixelExport {
    private byte[] data;

    private static byte f(int value) { return (byte) value; }

    private static long pack(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4) {
        return ((0xFFL & b1) << 24) | ((0xFFL & b2) << 16) |
                ((0xFFL & b3) << 8) | (0xFFL & b4);
    }

    public PixelExport() {
        data = new byte[] {
            // Row 1 - Red with Alpha FF -> 3F
            f(0xFF), f(0xFF), f(0x00), f(0x00),
            f(0xBF), f(0xFF), f(0x00), f(0x00),
            f(0x7F), f(0xFF), f(0x00), f(0x00),
            f(0x3F), f(0xFF), f(0x00), f(0x00),
            // Row 1 - Green with Alpha FF -> 3F
            f(0xFF), f(0x00), f(0xFF), f(0x00),
            f(0xBF), f(0x00), f(0xFF), f(0x00),
            f(0x7F), f(0x00), f(0xFF), f(0x00),
            f(0x3F), f(0x00), f(0xFF), f(0x00),
            // Row 1 - Blue with Alpha FF -> 3F
            f(0xFF), f(0x00), f(0x00), f(0xFF),
            f(0xBF), f(0x00), f(0x00), f(0xFF),
            f(0x7F), f(0x00), f(0x00), f(0xFF),
            f(0x3F), f(0x00), f(0x00), f(0xFF)
        };

        export(data, 4, 3, "foo", "png");
    }

    public void export(byte[] data, int width, int height, String filename, String ext) {
        String fullFilename = String.format("%s.%s", filename, ext);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4) {
            int row = i / (width * 4);
            int col = (i / 4) % width;
            image.setRGB(col, row, (int) pack(data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2], data[i+3]));
        }

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, ext, new File(fullFilename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.printf("Wrote: %s\n", fullFilename);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PixelExport();
    }
}
```

I could uses a `ByteBuffer` as well, but is this necessary? if I already have the indices?

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
buf.rewind();
while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
    int row = buf.position() / (width * 4);
    int col = (buf.position() / 4) % width;
    image.setRGB(col, row, (int) pack(buf.get(), buf.get(), buf.get(), buf.get()));
}
```

Comment: 4 byte... maybe you can simply set 1 int (which is 32 bit / 4 byte) but i'm not sure where you're aiming at....

Comment: Well, ints are signed, so I lose 1 byte on the alpha chanel if I go with an Integer... If I go with Long, this is not an issue, but I am storing 32 extra bits per pixel...

Comment: you can shift the signing bit by using the >>> operator (not the >> operator [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html] ), so you CAN use int for 4byte ops ... but i'm still not sure, how this would help you ...

Comment: So, I should store all ARGB values as a 4 byte integer and just "zero-shift (`>>>`)" when I need to decode the values? I just want to make the retrieval-to-pixel conversion fast, especially on larger size `BufferedImage`s.

Comment: that would work perfekt! i did it several times in my code! i could post some methodes if you like, but it seems like you're well known with bit-operations and masking and proper data types...